# Удаление с помощью запроса DELETE

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Как сделать удаление каждого сообщения. Что сдесь не так ?

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail ");
$r = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 $r[] = $row;
}

if (isset($_GET["delete"])) { 
$id = $_GET["delete"];
if(mysql_query("DELETE FROM `mail` WHERE id='$id' ")){
echo "<b>Сообщение удалено !</b>";
}
else
  echo "<b>Сообщение не может быть удалено!</b>";
}
?>

<table>
 <tr>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Сообщение</td>
 </tr>
 <?php foreach($r as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['messages']; ?><br>
 <a href="messages.php?delete=$id">Удалить</a></td>
    </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Все просто супер ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО :)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

надо вот так делать

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail ");
$r = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 $r[] = $row;
}

if (isset($_GET["delete"])) { 
$id = (int)$_GET["delete"];
if(mysql_query("DELETE FROM `mail` WHERE id='$id' ")){
echo "<b>Сообщение удалено !</b>";
}
else
  echo "<b>Сообщение не может быть удалено!</b>";
}
?>

<table>
 <tr>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Сообщение</td>
 </tr>
 <?php foreach($r as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['messages']; ?><br>
 <a href="messages.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Удалить</a></td>
    </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: "Фишка" данного ресурса в том, чтобы помочь человеку разобраться в проблеме, а не тупо решить проблему за него.

Comment: Ой ну я думаю наглядно все видно ... Вы вносили id в ссылку не из базы а из гет параметра(который поидее у вас был пустой)

Answer (score 3):

Откуда у вас значения берутся в переменной `$id`?

```
<a href="messages.php?delete=$id">Удалить</a></td>
```

Видимо, вы забыли где-то:

```
$id = $row['id'];
```

P.S.

В вопросы надо больше информативности вливать.

Comment: Если в место id написать цифру то и удаление будет по номеру id. А сдесь у каждого сообщения есть кнопка 'удалить' так вот как сделать что бы по нажатию этой кнопки удалялось то сообщение которому пренадлежит эта кнопка.

Comment: Ну так сделай то, что я тебе написал в первом сообщении.

Comment: Да вот что то не работает этот 
 
    $id = $row['id'];

Comment: Код покажите.

Comment: Собственно он весь сверху написан в самом вопросе. Остольные части страницы всего лишь html разметка и нечего более.

Comment: Зачем вы каждый раз отвечаете на свой же вопрос?

Покажите код, где вы сделали то, что я вам писал.

Comment: Для только что удаленного id формировать не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть ?delete=**1** где 1 это id

Запрос не передает значение, т.е. еденичку!

Comment: Так как сделать что бы не надо было писать 1, а можно было написать id.

Answer (score 0):

После удаления Вы формируете ответ в который вставлена строка с **уже удаленным** сообщением.

Видимо при формировании таблицы (ответа) надо учитывать ID уже удаленной строки.

Comment: А как это реализуется собственно ???